# Spring Integration-WebService

Tags: spring-integration

I have already implemented client webservice in apache cxf which is working fine.
Now I have been trying to implement the client webservice using spring integration.
While creating service I am getting below exception,Could you please anyone help me to resolve this.
Also advice me for any website to learn this spring-integration concepts.

Jars used for this service:

```
spring-integration-core-3.0.0
spring-integration-ws-3.0.0.RELEASE
spring-oxm-3.2.6.RELEASE
spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE
wsdl4j-1.6.1
spring-xml-2.1.3.RELEASE
```

> [org.jboss.modules] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Failed to define
>   class org.springframework.ws.client.support.WebServiceAccessor in
>   Module "deployment.TrailTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link
>   org/springframework/ws/client/support/WebServiceAccessor (Module
>   "deployment.TrailTest.war:main" from Service Module Loader):
>   org/springframework/xml/transform/TransformerObjectSupport    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:358)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
>     at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:605)    at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>     at
>   org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:490)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:503)
>     at
>   org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1057)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1030)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)   at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:231)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:132)
>     at
>   io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:526)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
>     at
>   org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/ws/client/support/WebServiceAccessor

You really have to be sure that `spring-ws-core-2.1.1.RELEASE` is on CLASSPATH.

If that is in the `WEB-INF/lib` and we see this problem, try to move it to the JBOSS server libs.